# How to insert combo box value into SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm new to C# so please check my code. It stops in `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` here, but when I simply insert date it works but not inserting with combo box.

Is the SQL query right or not?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace newpro
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object sel = comboBox1.SelectedValue;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\abdul samad\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\newpro\newpro\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO registor (Name, FullName, Password, Email, Gander) VALUES ('"+txtfname.Text+"','"+txtfname.Text+"', '"+txtuname.Text+"', '"+txtpass.Text+"', '"+txtemail.Text+"','"+comboBox1+"');",con);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd.Clone();

            MessageBox.Show("Record inserted");
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have a typo in your SQL -  **Gander** could be an error (depending on what you have in your table, anyway)

Comment: Well just like a textbox you have to use the property you want. Secondly you need to parameterize your query. This is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: Are you trying to insert the ComboBox control, or the value from the ComboBox?

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, which error? Also, the cmd.Clone() line is meaningless, don't mistake with cloSe!

Comment: i make tabe ID ,name fullname,username,password,email,gander
Id is primary key and auto increment  > i was use to do Php programing . I that auto increment we just  values("") empty like this ....

Answer (score 4):

you have to get the selected value from your Combobox. combobox1 retuns only the class name `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`

Besides others, it is recommended to use parameter .. like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\abdul samad\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\newpro\newpro\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        try
        {

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO registor (Name, FullName, Password, Email, Gander) VALUES (@Name,@Fullname,@Password,@Email, @Gander)"))
            {

                cmd.Connection = con;   
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", txtfname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fullname", txtfname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", txtpass.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", txtemail.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gander", comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem));

                con.Open()
                if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) 
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("Record inserted"); 
                }
                else
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("Record failed");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error during insert: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: God forbid SQL injection in your insert statement.........NEVER EVER use such queries, use parameters instead!!!!

Comment: This definitely looks better. I generally also add the SqlCommand around using statement, it will help ensure nothing about the connection is left behind.

Comment: error during insert : ExecuteNonQuery connectiong not properly initalized

Comment: SqlCommand takes SqlConnection as a parameter in its constructor. Also don't really need to open it until line before cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: @EdiG. you need to call con.Open() before executing con.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Not trying to be picky but there is one final issue I noticed. You are calling MessageBox.Show("Record inserted") without actually checking the result of cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() This is not necessarily correct as the insert query could fail and not create the record in the table. What you should be is in the line of if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) MessageBox.Show("Record inserted"); else MessageBox.Show("Record failed");

Answer (score 0):

```
public void insertfunction()
        { 

           string sqlconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sqlconn);
            cn.Open();
            String query = "insert into PatientRecords values(@Patient_Name,@Cnic,@Phone,@Address,@Age,@Doctor_Reference,@City)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,cn);
           // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Patient_Id", pid.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Patient_Name", pname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cnic", pcnic.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", pphone.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", paddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", cmbopcity.GetItemText(cmbopcity.SelectedItem));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", page.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Doctor_Reference", prefdoc.Text);


            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Record Successfully inserted");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Record failed");
            }
            cn.Close();


        }
```